# want to integrate quickbooks desktop with php

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am trying to integrate quickbook desktop version using following github repository:

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

but when I have created a custom new file to create customer into QB desktop application from our website using your sample code i.e. 
mydomain.com/qb_desktop/docs/web_connector/customer.php

After adding this file in web connector and run this, it keeps running continuously and keeps creating new unlimited customer until I add "die" in the php script  to stop forcefully this.

Can you please take a look into my following codes and let me know what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;
require_once '../../QuickBooks.php';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';
$map = array(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response'));
$errmap = array( 3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong');
$hooks = array();
$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;  
$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;
$soap_options = array();
$handler_options = array('deny_concurrent_logins' => false,
            'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false);
$driver_options = array();
$callback_options = array();
$dsn = 'mysqli://root:password@localhost/quickbooks';
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);

function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                        <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                            <City>Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                        <Email>Keith@ConsoliBYTE.com</Email>
                        <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
    return $xml;
}
function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{
    // Great, customer $ID has been added to QuickBooks with a QuickBooks
    //  ListID value of: $idents['ListID']
    //
    // We probably want to store that ListID in our database, so we can use it
    //  later. (You'll need to refer to the customer by either ListID or Name
    //  in other requests, say, to update the customer or to add an invoice for
    //  the customer.
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. It's impossible to help you without seeing what you're doing.

Comment: Please find the attached script in the following link. I have updated the required information like user, pass, database in my script.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15rRG8O39fyrQtD98iRBR76_zYLtiv730/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your question got closed because you didn't provide enough detail _in the actual question_. If you're still stuck, you can edit the question and make sure you include the code in your actual question.

Comment: I have already shared my scripts with you in the link. Can you please let me know, what exactly you are asking?

Comment: StackOverflow recommends you post code _inline, in the question itself_. This  provides syntax highlighting, easy copy-paste and edit, makes the post "durable" (Google docs can disappear or permissions can be changed, vs. the code in the question will stay), and makes the question "complete" without having to go off-site. You can read the recommendations here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Presently, it's difficult to read/copy/edit the code you posted, and the question itself is incomplete because the code isn't _in the question_. 

I'm trying to help you.

Comment: I have updated my question and added code in that as you said.

Comment: Thanks, I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Connector is based on SOAP, so what you're actually doing here is setting up a SOAP server that the Web Connector connects to.

What's important to realize here is that the Web Connector makes *many calls* to the SOAP service (e.g. many independent HTTP requests to your PHP script) *every single time it connects*. At the very least, even if there's no actual data to exchange, it makes at least 4 calls:

- clientVersion
- serverVersion
- authenticate
- closeConnection

The implication here is that whatever you put in your PHP script *runs at least 4 times* every time the Web Connector connects to your service to try to exchange data with QuickBooks. So every time the Web Connector connects, this piece of code *runs at least 4 times*:

```
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $primary_key_of_your_customer);
```

You *should not have this piece of code* in this file. It should be elsewhere. Remove it from this file, and your problem will go away.

Instead, *modify your web app* so that when a new customer is created in your web app, *you queue up the request for QuickBooks at that same time*. So somewhere in your application when you're doing something like this:

```
// Person submitted the form, so save the data they submitted into my database
$my_customer['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$my_customer['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];

$my_customer_id = $MyModelOrDatabase->insert('customer_table', $my_customer);
```

You should do this:

```
// Person submitted the form, so save the data they submitted into my database
$my_customer['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
$my_customer['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];

$my_customer_id = $MyModelOrDatabase->insert('customer_table', $my_customer);

if ($my_customer_id)
{
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $my_customer_id);
}
```

This puts a record in the queue for QuickBooks. Then, when the Web Connector connects it can pick this up out of the queue *that you already built* and process it.

If you look at the examples, there's an example which illustrates this:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector

Specifically, this example:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector/handler.php

Which looks something like this:

```
// Handle the form post
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    // Save the record
    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO
            my_customer_table
        (
            name, 
            fname, 
            lname
        ) VALUES (
            '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "', 
            '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['fname']) . "', 
            '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']) . "'
        )");

    // Get the primary key of the new record
    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    // Queue up the customer add 
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $id);

    die('Great, queued up a customer!');
}
```

And if you look at the docs, they actually explicitly warn you *not* to do what you've done so far:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php#L284

Docs:

```
    // NOTE: You would normally *never* want to do this in this file! This is 
    //  meant as an initial test ONLY. See example_web_connector_queueing.php for more 
    //  details!
    // 
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: This particular example of queueing something up will 
    //  only ever happen *once* when these scripts are first run/used. After 
    //  this initial test, you MUST do your queueing in another script. DO NOT 
    //  DO YOUR OWN QUEUEING IN THIS FILE! See 
    //  docs/example_web_connector_queueing.php for more details and examples 
    //  of queueing things up.
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Before using your suggestion, I am getting another issue. I have updated setup for QB desktop and web connector. When I add the ".qwc" file in web connector using "Add an application" button then getting the QBWC1039 error as you can see the attached screenshot. Also I am unable to remove the uploaded files from web connector.

https://nimb.ws/D1IyBC
https://nimb.ws/pYTARK

Comment: Also, just to let you know that I have added correct permission. So, this is not a permission issue.

Comment: You should probably ask that question separately, but -- start by closing the Web Connector, REBOOTING THE COMPUTER, opening QuickBooks and logging in with the username ADMIN,  and then re-opening the Web Connector FROM WITHIN QUICKBOOKS, BY GOING TO FILE > UPDATE WEB SERVICES. Then try to re-add the `.QWC` file from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I am able to add customer with my script.
I have one more question about this integration. Can you please help me on following question also?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770646/create-invoice-with-non-inventory-item-on-quick-books-desktop-in-php