# Create invoice with non-inventory item on Quick books desktop in PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks

I want to create an invoice with non-inventory items from my website to Quick books desktop application. I am using following github repository:
https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Please help me, how I can create an invoice with non-inventory items?

I have added my sample code to create an invoice with non-inventory items:

```
<?php
$primary_key_of_your_customer = 5;
require_once '../../QuickBooks.php';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$map = array(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE => array( '_quickbooks_invoice_add_request', '_quickbooks_invoice_add_response' ));
$errmap = array(3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong');
$hooks = array();
$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;  
$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;
$soap_options = array();
$handler_options = array( 'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
        'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
    );
$driver_options = array();
$callback_options = array();
$dsn = 'mysqli://root:password@localhost/quickbooks';
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE, $primary_key_of_your_customer);

function _quickbooks_invoice_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{    
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                        <InvoiceAddRq>
                            <InvoiceAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE">
                                <CustomerRef>
                                    <ListID >80000257-1578565322</ListID>
                                    <FullName >ConsoliBYTE, LLC (1001546518)</FullName>
                                </CustomerRef>
                                <RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber>
                                <BillAddress>
                                    <Addr1 >Addr1</Addr1>
                                    <Addr2 >Addr2</Addr2>
                                    <City >indore</City>
                                    <State >TX</State>
                                    <PostalCode >482201</PostalCode>
                                    <Country >US</Country>
                                    <Note >Notes</Note>
                                </BillAddress>
                                <ShipAddress>
                                    <Addr1 >old palasia</Addr1>
                                    <Addr2 >stree 123</Addr2>
                                    <City >Katni</City>
                                    <State >TX</State>
                                    <PostalCode >48002</PostalCode>
                                    <Country >US</Country>
                                    <Note >Shipping</Note>
                                </ShipAddress>
                                <IsPending >true</IsPending>
                                <PONumber >PONumber</PONumber>
                                <ShipMethodRef>
                                    <ListID ></ListID>
                                    <FullName >Fedex</FullName>
                                </ShipMethodRef>
                                <Other >Other</Other>
                                <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                    <ItemRef>
                                        <FullName >item</FullName>
                                    </ItemRef>
                                    <Desc >item Desc</Desc>
                                    <Quantity >1</Quantity>
                                    <UnitOfMeasure >UnitOfMeasure</UnitOfMeasure>
                                    <Rate >1.5</Rate>
                                    <Amount >1.5</Amount>
                                    <Other1 >Other1</Other1>
                                    <Other2 >Other2</Other2>
                                </InvoiceLineAdd>
                            </InvoiceAdd>
                        </InvoiceAddRq>
                    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';
    return $xml;
}

function _quickbooks_invoice_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{

}

function _quickbooks_error_stringtoolong($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You'd need to be more specific on what help you require.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried/written so far so we can assist.

Comment: Getting three different kind of errors:

A. errorMsg="3040: There was an error when converting the amount "1.5" in the field "Amount". "
 Can you please let me know, what exactly wrong in the code?

 ///////////////////////
B. 3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Ship Method "Fedex" in the Invoice.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list.
 Do I need to create shiping method before create the invoice?

Comment: C. 3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Item "item" in the Invoice line. QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument. The specified record does not exist in the list.
 Want to create non-inventory items with invoice but as per the error message I think I need to add items on QB to pass their reference. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track here. Let's talk about the specific error messages you're getting:

> 3040: There was an error when converting the amount "1.5" in the field "Amount"

Dollar amounts in QuickBooks have 2 decimal places. e.g. you need to send:

```
<Rate>1.50</Rate>
<Amount>1.50</Amount>
```

> 3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Ship Method "Fedex" in the Invoice. QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument. The specified record does not exist in the list.

QuickBooks is, at it's core, a relational database. Think of `ShipMethodRef/FullName` (and/or `ShipMethodRef/ListID`) as a foreign key constraint.

If you try to insert something and reference a foreign key that doesn't exist, you get an error. So you'll *either* need to:

1. Go into the QuickBooks UI, and create a ship method named `Fedex` (This is probably your best choice, since `Ship Method`s tend to not change often and there's usually not too many of them. In QuickBooks choose `Lists > Customer & Vendor Profile Lists > Item List` )

or

2. Make a `ShipMethodAdd` call to create the ship method (docs: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/shipmethodadd )

or

3. You could leave out the `<ShipMethodRef>` entirely if you don't want to set it at all

You should also decide whether you're going to send a `ListID` or a `FullName`. Don't send both, it just makes errors more confusing. I'd recommend you send the `FullName` only. If you want to send the `ListID` you'll have to query QuickBooks to get the `ListID` values back (they do not show in the QuickBooks UI).

> 3140: There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Item "item" in the Invoice line. QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument. The specified record does not exist in the list.

This is a very similar error to the `ShipMethod` error above. You reference an item:

```
<ItemRef>
  <FullName >item</FullName>
</ItemRef>
```

And QuickBooks is telling you that that item *does not exist*. Similar to `Ship Method`, you have to either:

1. Create it (or use an existing item) via the QuickBooks UI (in QuickBooks choose `Lists > Item List` )

or

2. Create it via the API (docs: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/itemnoninventoryadd )

You don't have option `3.` here because it's a required field for invoices.

Since you're just getting started with QuickBooks development, *I would HIGHLY RECOMMEND that you go with option `1.` above*.

Tackle `2.` only if you need to, and after you have the basics of your integration down (e.g. once you've seen some invoices actually get created successfully).

One other thing to watch for -- QuickBooks has a concept of a "sub-item". Think of it like this:

```
Shirts
 > T-Shirts
  > Red T-Shirts
  > Blue T-Shirts
  > Green T-Shirts
```

Each of those is an `Item`, *but* because they are in a nested hierarchy (e.g. `T-Shirts` is a *child item/sub-item* of `Shirts`) the `FullName` values *reflect that hierarchy*:

```
Shirts              (name=Shirts, FullName=Shirts)
 > T-Shirts         (name=T-Shirts, FullName=Shirts:T-Shirts)
  > Red T-Shirts    (name=Red T-Shirts, FullName=Shirts:T-Shirts:Red T-Shirts)
  > Blue T-Shirts   (name=Red T-Shirts, FullName=Shirts:T-Shirts:Blue T-Shirts) 
  > Green T-Shirts  (name=Red T-Shirts, FullName=Shirts:T-Shirts:Green T-Shirts)
```

So if you see the item in QuickBooks... but you're still getting errors about `FullName`, make sure you're really using the whole `FullName` instead of just the `Name` of the thing.